# How can I remove merged branch which is already push to origin

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

For example, I have 1 defect issue ,which developer create new branch, and fixed it in branch name "fix_#1_backyard_data_displayed". Then, I merge it into branch "beta" to test it. After a while, another tester merged another branchs like "fix_2" and "fix_3" to "fix_20" into "beta" and test it. After that, I found my first merged "fix_#1_backyard_data_displayed" branch is buggy and make our application unstable.

Now, how can I remove merged branch which is already push to origin without disturbing "fix_2" and "fix_3" to "fix_20"?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "remove merged branch"? Delete it from the remote, or revert the commits you made in this branch?

Comment: it's revert sorry for the misunderstanding, and I found the solution here : # branch="fix1"; git log --all --pretty=format:"%H %s" | grep -i "Merge branch '$branch'" | grep -v "Revert" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git revert -m 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

In the `beta` branch:

1. Find the SHA1 of the commit that corresponds to the merge.
2. Run `git revert <sha1> -m 1`

There is a caveat: Git will still think that this feature branch is merged into the `beta` branch, and to merge this branch again you'll need to revert (again) the commit introduced by this `git revert` before merging.

#### Longer version

The command in Git to undo a commit is `revert`. For merge commits, you need to specify the "mainline" branch with the `-m` switch. In your case, it should probably be 1:

> Usually you cannot revert a merge because you do not know which side of the merge should be considered the
>      mainline. This option specifies the parent number (starting from 1) of the mainline and allows revert to
>      reverse the change relative to the specified parent.
>
> Reverting a merge commit declares that you will never want the tree changes brought in by the merge. As a
>      result, later merges will only bring in tree changes introduced by commits that are not ancestors of the
>      previously reverted merge. This may or may not be what you want.
>
> See the revert-a-faulty-merge How-To[1] for more details.

(Source: `git help revert`)

The following `sh` script demonstrates this. The first `revert` command reverts the commit that merged the `fix1` branch, in this case it is the second-to-last commit, i.e., `HEAD^`. After reverting, before merging the `fix1` branch again, the revert needs to be undone with another `revert` command:

```
#!/bin/sh

git init test
cd test

touch a
git add a
git commit -m a

git checkout -b fix1
touch b
git add b
git commit -m b

git checkout -b fix2 master
touch c
git add c
git commit -m c

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-edit fix1
git merge --no-ff --no-edit fix2

git revert --no-edit HEAD^ -m 1

git checkout fix1
echo "fix b" > b
git add b
git commit -m bb

git checkout master
# git merge fix1 # this will give an error!

# revert changes introduced by revert before merging
git revert --no-edit HEAD
git merge --no-ff --no-edit fix1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

```
branch_to_revert="fix1"; git log --all --pretty=format:"%H %s" | grep -i "Merge branch '$branch_to_revert'" | grep -v "Revert" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git revert -m 1
```